# Popover placement and doesnt overflow outside parent element

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a ngprime table where the header row has a column field with a popover where placement is set as top, however it is instead covering the field. I figured out this is because it can't display outside the parent div, so it ignores the placement instead.

`<th class ="popover_enabled text-center" [popover]="customPopup" container="body" placement="top">FieldName</th>`

I've tried resolving it in css styling

```
.popover-content.popover-body{
margin-top-30px;
}
```

which works but affected other popovers and as it is a generated element, I want to stay away from that route. I've also tried setting the overflow: visible in parent div to no avail. Any suggestions are welcome to solve this issue as I'm stumped.

Comment: We need a full example of the code that isn't working, so we can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when dealing with tooltips there is a parameter of anchor to the tooltip element. In this case, it's the `appendTo` property, where the desired value should probably be `body`.

From the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v14-lts/tooltip):

`appendTo`  string  *Target element to attach the overlay, valid values are "body", "target" or a local ng-template variable of another element (note: use binding with brackets for template variables, e.g. [appendTo]="mydiv" for a div element having #mydiv as variable name).*

```js
<input type="text" pTooltip="Enter your username" appendTo="body">
```